# how can i call another method within the tap property in receipt card in bot application using visual C#

Tags: c#, botframework

I am creating a bot using bot application.I want to call another method when tapping the card.I couldn't call another method within the tap property in receipt card.
Can anyone help me in calling a method within tap property?

Comment: properties don't normally contain methods. It's possible if you are writing a property, that you could call another method from within its getter or setter, that's done exactly the same way as it is from any other place in your code. What's are you stuck with, exactly? Post the code and show us precisely what you mean.

Comment: I couldn't place the whole code.I can be able to display the receipt card which contains some details.After that, I want to display further details, if a user clicks on the card.My problem is how to call a method which retrieves the further details when tapping on the card.

Comment: We don't need the whole code, need the _relevant part_ of the code. Just enough to explain the issue / reproduce the problem. I have no idea what you mean by cards - is it some UI element? But basically if you have some kind of event like a "tap" or a "click", then in the event handler for that, you can write any code you like including calling other methods. Do you know how to handle the tap/click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the `ReceiptCard` class, you can find it enable us to specify [CardAction](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.cardaction) for `Tap` property.

```
//
// Summary:
//     This action will be activated when user taps on the card
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tap")]
public CardAction Tap { get; set; }
```

> I couldn't call another method within the tap property in receipt card.

As far as I know, we can not call and execute user defined methods directly via ReceiptCard Tap property. If you want retrieve and display further details after user click on the card, you can try to send back message to bot via a **postBack** (or **imBack**) CardAction and then retrieve more detailed information based on postback value. The following sample is for your reference.

```
CardAction pbv = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "postbackval-category-C1",
    Type = "imBack",
    Title = "image Page"
};

ReceiptCard plCard = new ReceiptCard()
{
    Title = "Receipt Card",
    Items = receiptList,
    Total = "112.77",
    Tax = "27.52",
    Tap = pbv
};


if (activity.Text.StartsWith("postbackval"))
{
    string category = activity.Text.Split('-')[2].ToString();

    //retriveve more details based on postback value
}
else
{
    //do other operations  
}
```